# Formula to copy over text between the words "CONTACT:" and the symbol "("

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a cell that has contract information in it. I need a formula that will pull the name after the word "CONTACTS:"

The customers name is sometimes two, sometimes three words. However it is always followed by a space and then a parentheses.

The format looks like:

CONTACTS: *Customers Name Here* (888) 888-8888

and i need the italicized text.

The formula below seems to work if i use (888) in the function but not just one parentheses. I cannot use (888) because the area codes are sometimes defferent.

=MID(K2,SEARCH("CONTACTS:",K2)+9,SEARCH("(888)",K2)-SEARCH("CONTACTS:",K2)-10)

Answer (score 1):

The `REGEXEXTRACT` function should do what you need:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT("CONTACT: one two three (213)((((", "CONTACT: (.*?) \(")
```

outputs:

```
one two three
```

It extracts everything between "CONTACT: " and the first " (" in the cell, counting the spaces.

Comment: In my case there are a ton of parenthesis in the cell after the line that has this info, so howw can i arrange it so that once it reaches the FIRST "(" after the word CONTACTS: the function stops?

Comment: The `(.*?)` in the regex will do it, matching "anything, but as little as possible". If you need to do string manipulations and matching frequently, I recommend learning how to use regexes ("regular expressions").

Comment: So if I have all the info in cell K2, why am i getting an error with this? =REGEXEXTRACT(K2, "CONTACTS: (.*?) \(")

Comment: In the regex, parens characters `()` have a special meaning - they're used to group text together, e.g. `(.*?)` is a group. If you want that last `(` to mean "match a left parens", you'll need to escape it with a backslash: `\(`.

Comment: =REGEXEXTRACT(K2, "CONTACTS: (.*?) /(") does not work either

Comment: I get why the backslash is needed for the parenthesis from my c++ class, but i still dont understand why its not working. Im looking here for reference as well https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en

Comment: Could it be that "Google products use RE2 for regular expressions. Learn more on how to use RE2 expressions." on this page i do not see the (.*?) regex. https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt. Im getting the error ""CONTACTS: (.*?) /(" is not a valid regular expression."

Comment: It's because you've used a forward slash `/`, not a backslash ``\``. You don't see `(.*?)` because it's a combination of three separate elements: parens grouping `()`, wildcard `.`, and non-greedy modifier for wildcard `?`

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:
   =MID(K12,SEARCH("Contacts:",K12)+10,SEARCH("(",K12,SEARCH("Contacts",K12))-SEARCH("Contacts",K12)-LEN("Contacts: ")-1)

Comment: That doesnt work becasue there is a lot more info in the cell then just the format i typed above. The cell has contract numbers, property addresses, workorder items, billing information, ect. However there is only ONE spot where the word "CONTACTS:" is used and after the name of the customer there is a phone number starting with "("

Comment: This formula should work as long as all cells are as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i ended up using and it works GREAT!

=ArrayFormula(if(K2:K="","",REGEXEXTRACT(K2:K, "CONTACTS: (.*?) (")))

Comment: Are you sure? - you still haven't escaped that last `(` in your regex with a backslash ``\`` (last time you used a forward slash `/`). Also, if you felt my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it as an answer or vote it up?